# Free resources in blocked RabbitMQ connection

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-4.8, rabbitmq.client

I have a very basic demo application for testing the RabbitMQ blocking behaviour. I use RabbitMQ 3.10.6 with the .NET library RabbitMQ.Client 6.2.4 in .NET Framework 4.8.

The connection is created using `ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()` and uses `AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true`.

The application creates one channel and one queue for sending messages:

```
IModel sendChannel = Connection.CreateModel();
sendChannel.ConfirmSelect();
sendChannel.QueueDeclare("sendQueueName", true, false, false);
```

For receiving messages, again one channel and one queue are created:

```
IModel receiveChannel = Connection.CreateModel();
receiveChannel.ConfirmSelect();
receiveChannel.QueueDeclare("receiveQueueName", true, false, false);
var receiveQueueConsumer = new QueueConsumer(receiveChannel); // This is my own class which inherits from 'DefaultBasicConsumer' and passes 'receiveChannel' to its base in the constructor.
receiveChannel.BasicConsume("receiveQueueName", false, receiveQueueConsumer);
```

Now I fill my disk until the configured threshold in the RabbitMQ config file is reached.
As expected, the `ConnectionBlocked` event is fired. The connection now is in state "blocking".

Now I queue a message. AMQP properties are added to the message using `channel.CreateBasicProperties()` with `Persistent = true`. It is then queued:

```
sendChannel.BasicPublish("", "sendQueueName", amqpProperties, someBytes);
sendChannel.WaitForConfirms(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // Returns as expected after 5 seconds with return value 'true'.
```

The connection now is in state "blocked".

Now I shut down my demo application and I have to realize that disposing does not work as expected.

```
sendChannel.Close(); // Blocks for 10 seconds.
if (receiveChannel.IsOpen) receiveChannel.BasicCancel(ConsumerTags.First()); // In 'receiveQueueConsumer'. Throws a 'TimeoutException'.
Connection.Close(); // Freezes for at least a minute.
```

The behaviour is the same when calling `Dispose()` or `Abort()` instead of `Close()`. When I finally force kill the application (or when I set a timeout for `Abort()`) then the application closes but the underlying connection and channels are not removed. The connection still is in state "blocked".

At least once there is enough space on the disk again, the blocked connections and their channels are automatically removed by the broker. Without the need to restart it.

[Here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/discussions/issues/35) and [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html) it sounds like the broker just won't react when it is "blocked".

> There can be a broad number of reasons for a timeout, from a genuine connection interruption to a resource alarm in effect that prevents target node from reading any data coming from clients unless the alarm clears.

> Nodes will temporarily block publishing connections by suspending reading from client connection.

Which would mean I can't free my resources unless I restart the broker or I make sure that the broker has plenty of resources to turn off the resource alarm. Is there an official confirmation for this? Or how do I need to adjust the dispose mechanism to make it work when the broker is blocked?